# Intercept only specific errors Nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm using Nginx as reverse proxy. With the directive `proxy_intercept_errors` I can intercept 50x errors from remote server and handle them. I'm looking for a way to handle a specific error only if was generated from my nginx reverse proxy, and not from the remote server. How can I do?

Comment: Then you should use `error_page` then https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page

Comment: I'm using that directive to show custom error pages for intercepted errors, in addition to proxy_intercept_errors. I want to show custom error page for a specific error only if was generated by Nginx reverse proxy.

Comment: Then you can use `error_page`, inside that `proxy_pass` block

Comment: I will try with this solution. Thanks